# Em quais páginas devo colocar o código do google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics-api

No manual fala pra colocar em todas as páginas, mas isso inclui as páginas que só podem ser acessadas após o login?

Tem como o google analytics enxergar estas páginas?

Por exemplo, se a minha única página com o analytics é a `index.php`, isso fará com que não seja computado corretamente o tempo que o usuário passou no site, o índice de rejeição etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A resposta para as 3 perguntas é **sim**.

É preciso colocar o [código de acompanhamento](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=pt-BR) em todas as páginas que se quiser rastrear. Mesmo a página tendo autenticação, o analytics consegue "enxergar" os dados relevantes, e fornecer as features que queremos, como número de acessos, tempo de permanência, taxa de rejeição etc... e o mais importante imo, que é o [fluxo de comportamento](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2785577?hl=pt-BR).

O local indicado pelo google para a colocação do código de acompanhamento é entre as tags `head`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<head>
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
</head>
```

Vide página de ajuda no [developers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/?hl=pt-br).

Conforme indicado pelo @Ricardo Gaya, na resposta acima, também é possível (e indicado) utilizar um tag manager, como [o do próprio google](https://www.google.com/intl/pt-BR/tagmanager/), para tornar o carregamento assíncrono.

Answer (score 2):

Exato! Você deve implementar dentro do  do site.

Uma boa prática é utilizar um Tag Manager como o Google Tag Manager, pois torna o carregamento assíncrono. Isso é apenas umas das vantagens de utilizar um tag manager.

Comment: Dei +1 nesta resposta, pela dica importante do tag maganer, mas não achei que ela respondeu satisfatoriamente a pergunta, então como já faz tempo que postei, e já sei a resposta, resolvi fazer uma tbm com maiores informações.

Answer (score -1):

Por padrão de convenção, os códigos em JS ficam dentro do `<head> </head>` do HTML !

Mas se você colocar em qualquer lugar da página HTML o script irá funcionar normalmente